# How to take in an int value and return it with asterisks

Tags: java

New to Java, Wondering how to take an integer and output it with the first 12 numbers as *'s.
Context being that my daily Java challenge is:
"Write a program that takes a credit card number and only displays the last four characters. The rest of the card number must be replaced by ***s."

I began with a simple method that outputs the int itself...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class creditHide {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            // Defines the cc number as an integer...
        int cCNumber;
            // Defines Scanner for the users' input...
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            // Prints a prompt for the users' cCNumber...
        System.out.print("CREDIT CARD: ");
            // Assigns the next input as the users' cCNumber...
        cCNumber = scanner.nextInt();

        // (Here I would want a way of hiding the first 12 numbers)

            // Test to make sure it reads correctly...
        System.out.println(cCNumber);
    }
}
```

I imagine I would have to rethink my original way of doing it, open to any soloutions.
Thank you :)

*Sleep*

Comment: Read the requirement again, in terms of what the result will look like. How you get there shouldn't matter: there is no reason to _replace_ anything if what you need is a final result that consists of 12 asterisks, followed by the last four "letters" of your input. Just make a new string.

Comment: One small tipp: Just because it is called "Credit Card **Number**" doesn't mean you have to treat it like a number in your code. Unless the requirement states you have to use int/long you might want to just take the credit card number input as a simple String. Or if you want to use a number data type you should at least check what the maximum value for int is and think about how you could put a 16 digit credit card number into that int.

Comment: Yes, makes sense now I've looked back at the code with both of your comments. Using a string makes sense. But still unsure how to tell the output to change the first 12 'items' to asterisks.
Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;  
                                                                         
public class creditHide {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long cardNumber;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        cardNumber = scan.nextLong();
        int a = (int)(cardNumber % 10000);
        System.out.println("card number **** **** **** " + a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what you want to do using a regular expression to check the validity of the input and, if the provided card number is valid, hide the first 12 digits:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Scanner;

class creditHide {

    private static Pattern CC_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d{4} \\d{4} \\d{4} (\\d{4})");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Defines the cc number as an integer...
        String cCNumber;

        // Defines Scanner for the users' input...
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prints a prompt for the users' cCNumber...
        System.out.print("CREDIT CARD: ");

        // Assigns the next input as the users' cCNumber...
        cCNumber = scanner.nextLine();

        // Check for a valid credit card number, and hide first 12 digits of credit card number
        Matcher m = CC_PATTERN.matcher(cCNumber.strip());
        if (m.matches())
            cCNumber = String.format("**** **** **** %s", m.group(1));
        else
            // TODO: Do something more rigorous when an invalid card is entered
            cCNumber = "invalid";

        // Test to make sure it reads correctly...
        System.out.println(cCNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to formulate a somewhat good soloution, using all the suggestions so thank you all very much.

The following is the soloution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;                                                                               // Imports Scanner utilization
public class creditHide {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String cCNumber;                                                                                
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in;                                                        
        System.out.print("CREDIT CARD: ");                                                                  
        cCNumber = scanner.next();                                                                      
        if(cCNumber.length()>16)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR 001, INVALID: TOO MANY VALUES, Please insert 16 values.");
        }
        else if(cCNumber.length()<16)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR 002, INVALID: NOT ENOUGH VALUES, Please insert 16 values.");
        }
        else if(cCNumber.length() == 16)
        {
            String cCNumber2 = cCNumber.replace(cCNumber, "************" + cCNumber.substring(12)); characters
            System.out.println(cCNumber2);                                                              
        }                                                               
        else
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR 003, INVALID: INVALID VALUES, Please insert 16 values.");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm just working on a more comprehensive error-handeling for different inputs.

Thank you everyone :)

*sleep*